# Trasform txt containing HTML to Plain Text

Tags: jsoup, html-to-text

I am trying to find a tool to parse a TXT file, containing html, to plain text, while keeping it formatted, whith lists and so on

I have been able to find this http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.html
which works perfeclty. Only problem is that it reads an URL, not a file. I tried making some changes to the code but without success

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to have it read my txt file as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start investigating the source code of the example program: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/examples/HtmlToPlainText.java

It is pretty easy to load the html from a file instead of an URL. JSoup can easily parse a string.

**Example**

```
String fileName = "YOURFILE.htm";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File(fileName) );
String content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
scanner.close() // Put this call in a finally block

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
//do whatever with the JSoup document
```

Comment: I tried changing the code a bit but the problem is that it creates Document object reading from the URL, using multiple functions of various classes, and i haven't been able to have it read the file instead. i tried passing the local file as URL with the file:/// prefix but it only accepts HTTP and HTTPS